# jquery slimscroll - mousewheel propagation

Tags: jquery

How to avoid the mousewheel to propagate to the body?

When you scroll the red div the body scrolls?

On their demo website there is no propagation

## code

```
<div class="main">
    <div>
        <div class="content">
            test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
            test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
            test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.main {
    height:1000px;
    background:gray;
}

.content {
    background:red;
}

$('.content').slimScroll({
    position : 'right',
    height : 150,
    railVisible: true,
    alwaysVisible: true
});
```

## jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/a6c6rszt/2/

## slimscroll demo page

http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll/

Comment: works fine for me in firefox and chrome, what browser are you using?

Comment: It looks like slimscroll doens't work in chrome in my example.. I'm using Firefox 33.. When you scroll with the mousewheel in the red area the body scrolls

Comment: But it seems like that chrome just can't handle the extern file source, if you copy the script's code above your javascript it works in chrome, too. http://jsfiddle.net/a6c6rszt/1/

Comment: done.. it looks like it works in chrome.. but it still doesn't work i FF.. link to jsfiddle updated

Comment: strange, works just fine for me in FF